# What is a "template" good for in CakePHPs E-Mailcomponent?

Tags: cakephp

I'm a bit confused using the Cake's (2.3) Email-Class. It appears that we are able to define a "template", a "layout" and a "theme" whereas I only understand the usage of Layouts (located in /app/View/Layouts/Emails).

It seems that everything can be defined in the Layout, but the Template seems do be necessary (at least an empty file) but I don't understand the context because to me it seems that it does not matter what I put in there.

The concept of the theme is even more nebulous to me. Maybe someone can give me a hint here. I found a discussin in a mailing-list which was not really enlightning. The documentation does not reveal this too.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html

--
Edit: Fixed confusing typo.
Edit2: CakeEmail is used directly - not the component.

Comment: Don't use Email-Component, better use CakeEmail directly. And no, template/layout is not necessary. You can also send template-less emails.

Comment: Uups... my wrong using CakeEmail Class - will update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

template is view (in terms of ordinary pages)
layout for emails is as layout for views (in terms of ordinary pages)

layout should contain some common elements like logo and etc

and you can push data to templates like push data to view from controller

Please, check following example:

from custom EmailComponent

```
public function restore_password($user_to_send_restore_link) {
    $email = new CakeEmail('default');
    $email->emailFormat('both');
    $email->template('restore_password', 'emaillayout');

    $email->to(array($user_to_send_restore_link['User']['email']));
    $email->from(array(GENERAL_FROM_EMAIL => 'seqrd support team'));
    $subject = 'Restore password link';
    $email->subject($subject);

    $email_data = array(
        'hash' => $user_to_send_restore_link['User']['hash']);
    $email->viewVars($email_data);

    return $email->send();
}
```

app/View/Emails/html/restore_password.ctp

```
<p> Please, follow link <?php echo $this->Html->link('restore password link', Router::url(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'restore_password_form', $hash), true)); ?> to restore password</p>
```

app/View/Layouts/Emails/html/emaillayout.ctp

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $title_for_layout;?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo $this->fetch('content');?>

</body>
</html>
```

Theme it's next step of abstraction, there you can fast change whole styles of all emails, but not change  code significantly.

Notes:  `viewVars` method pass variables not only into template, but in email layout too.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. But where do you use your $email_data now? So the process seems to be 'Pass ViewVars to template' then pass template to Layout (but where to you define $content_for_layout?). Is this correct? Are ViewVars passed to Template AND Layout?

Comment: I pass variables via = `$email->viewVars($email_data);`  $content_for_layout it's old versions cakephp convention.  now seems should be used `echo $this->fetch('content');` see here: `app/View/Layouts/Emails/html/default.ctp`, but $content_for_layout still work . And Yes, viewVars pass parameters to email layout too. Will update answer in several minutes

Comment: K - thanks again for clarification. But where does the style now come into play?

Comment: Not sure, that I understand your question, but seems if you mean how define styles for emails, then it's better to use  inline styles or style html element in email layout. For images,  not attach them, but create normal img elements there src is simple url of image. IMHO this is best approach to get reasonable result for most of email clients.

Comment: Thanks again for clarifying. :)